# React with Firebase - splitting authorisation between CRUD actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, permissions, firebase-security

I am trying to use react with firebase to make an app that allows all users to read everything and some users to write to some functions.

At the moment, I have my firestore security rules set to allow all users to read and write everything, and then I have a withAuthorisation wrapper that I want to put around a component that contains a link to make write a new document. I know this isn't secure, but I'm just trying to get the hang of how to separate the code so that I can build view layers that render the content in line with the permissions I write.

At the moment I have a references list, which is an index of all the references created. At the bottom of that list, I have a component called 'AddReference' which is a link to the form to make a new reference.

The list is not wrapped in my withAuthorisation wrapper. The AddReference component is wrapped.

I am expecting to be logged out and render the list to all users - (everyone can read the index) but a logged out user should not see the AddReference link.

Instead, the entire list is blocked behind an authentication redirect.

My list of all the references has:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { withFirebase } from '../../Firebase/Index';
import * as ROUTES from '../../../constants/Routes';
import { ReferencesList } from './ReferencesList';
import {  Layout, Typography, Card, List, Button, Divider } from 'antd';
import {ReferencesForm} from './Form';
import AddReference from './AddReference';

const { Content } = Layout 
const { Title, Paragraph, Text } = Typography;


class ReferencesPage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Content
            style={{
              background: '#fff',
              padding: 24,
              margin: "auto",
              minHeight: 280,
              width: '90%'
            }}
          >
            <ReferencesList/>
            <br/>
            <AddReference />
          </Content>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReferencesPage;
```

My AddReference component has:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { withFirebase } from '../../Firebase/Index';
import * as ROUTES from '../../../constants/Routes';
import { ReferencesList } from './ReferencesList';
import {  Layout, Typography, Card, List, Button, Divider } from 'antd';
import {ReferencesForm} from './Form';
import { AuthUserContext, withAuthorization, withEmailVerification } from '../../Session/Index';


const { Content } = Layout 
const { Title, Paragraph, Text } = Typography;


const AddReference = () => (

<AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser => (


        <div>

                <Divider></Divider>
                <div style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center"
                }}>
                <Link to={ROUTES.REFERENCESFORM}>Add a Reference</Link>
                </div>



        </div>

)}
</AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);


const condition = authUser => !!authUser;
export default compose(
// withEmailVerification,
withAuthorization(condition),
)(AddReference);
```

My withAuthorisation wrapper has:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase/Index';
import AuthUserContext from './Context';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/Routes';


const withAuthorization = condition => Component => {
  class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
    // componentDidMount() {
    //   this.listener = 
this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
    //     if (!condition(authUser)) {
    //       this.props.history.push(ROUTES.SIGN_IN);
    //     }
    //   });
    // }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.onAuthUserListener(
        authUser => {
          if (!condition(authUser)) {
            this.props.history.push(ROUTES.SIGN_IN);
          }
        },
        () => this.props.history.push(ROUTES.SIGN_IN),
      );
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.listener();
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
          {authUser =>
            condition(authUser) ? <Component {...this.props} /> : null
          }
        </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
      );
    }
  }
  return compose(
    withRouter,
    withFirebase,
  )(WithAuthorization);
};
export default withAuthorization;
```

Is it possible to have a component that is wrapped inside an authorisation requirement rendered on a page that is not wrapped? I still want to show the content of the list (other than the AddReference component) for users that do not satisfy the authorisation condition.

Answer (score 3):

***1> how to implement permissions in an optimize way ?***

**Answer:**

[Best practice for React Router user roles (Firebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356681/best-practice-for-react-router-user-roles-firebase)

[Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) and React Apps](https://auth0.com/blog/role-based-access-control-rbac-and-react-apps/).

2> ***Is it possible to have a component that is wrapped inside an authorisation requirement rendered on a page that is not wrapped? I still want to show the content of the list (other than the AddReference component) for users that do not satisfy the authorisation condition.***

**Short Answer:** Yes, make the page accessible to all users and hide the content of the page which should not be visible to public.

**Answer:** Well, we need to have a global state ( **REDUX**, **localStorage**, etc ) in which we will store user roles ( guest, login etc ) at the time initialization. then when we need to hide an element from component, we just have to check for a value like below

```
//set state.userRole from globalState in init function.
(this.state.userRole == 'login') ?
<Icon name='md-log-out' style={styles.logoutIcon} button onPress={() =>
            Alert.alert(
                'Log out',
                'Do you want to logout?',
                [
                    { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => { return null } },
                    {
                        text: 'Confirm', onPress: () => {this.logout()}
                    },
                ],
                { cancelable: false }
            )
        }/>
        :
        <View />;
```

Comment: Thanks - but I'm specifically looking to figure out how the HOC can be applied, at component level, to accept conditions specified in the way I have shown.

Comment: (this.state.userRole == 'login') ? <ComponentOne /> : <ComponentTwo />; you can  apply condition on component this above. Or I think I havent understand your requirements, it would be better with a simple diagram

Comment: No - that's not what I'm looking for. I have a withAuthorization wrapper that accepts conditions. It wraps components. Where I have a page that renders 2 components and 1 is wrapped and the other is not, the inclusion of the wrapper on one of the components should not impact on the second, unwrapped component being rendered. At the moment, that's not what's happening.

Comment: Okay looks like I completely mistaken your problem. Allow me some more time to experiment with this thanks.